# Microarray with n channels

Tags: genetics, microarray

Recently we've been learning about Microarrays, and the typical method seems to be to run a two channel microarray where your RNA from each cell is labelled with a different fluorescent marker, and then the relative intensity of the fluorescent label can be used to identify a ratio of relative gene expression.

I was wondering if it would be possible to use a larger quantity of DNA sequences on the array and then run a number of sets of RNA fragments - for example, say you extract RNA from cells from a cell culture at constant time intervals, then you label them with fluorescent markers which are orders, and then scan the fluorescent labels to find out how the expression varies over time?

Why wouldn't this work?

Thanks!